# Creating 2 dimesional array with user input and find sum of specific columns

Tags: java, arrays, input, sum

Please assist with my code. 
There must be 3 rows and 4 columns in the array.
The user must be able to enter doubles for the first 2 columns.
Then I should be able to calculate the sum of each column in the array.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      // Implement scanner
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Create loop for accepting matrix input
      // Determine row size
      System.out.println("Please enter the number 3 for the number of rows in the array:");
      int row = input.nextInt();
      //Rule for row not being 3
      while (row != 3)
      {
      System.out.println("Sorry, there must be 3 rows.");
      row = input.nextInt();
      }

      // Determine column size
      System.out.println("Please enter the number 4 for the number of columns in the array:");
      int column = input.nextInt();
      //Rule for column not being 4
      while (column != 4)
      {
      System.out.println("Sorry, there must be 4 columns.");
      column = input.nextInt();
      }

      // Declare array with row and columns the user gave
      int[][] userArray = new int[row][column];
      //Informing user how data is inputted and saved
      System.out.print("Note that the following inputs saves the numbers from left to right. So after entering 4 digits it moves onto the next row.");
      System.out.println("\n");
      for(int i=0;i < row ; i++)
      {
        for(int j=0; j< column; j++)
        { 
        System.out.print("Please enter a value for the array:["+i+"]["+j+"]");
        int val = input.nextInt();
        userArray[i][j] = val;
        }
      }
      printMatrix(userArray, row, column);
    }

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] array, int row, int column)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
          System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
          System.out.println();
      }
    }
}
```

The printed output should be, depending on user input:

1.9 2.3 5 1

5.0 7.3 6 8

2.4 3.1 3 2

The sum of column 1 is: 9.3

The sum of column 2 is: 12.7

The sum of column 3 is: 14

The sum of column 4 is: 11

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now need to add the array values by column. It can be as easy as:

```
private void printSumForColumn(int[][] array, int col)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
    sum += array[i][col];
  }
  System.out.println("The sum of column " + col + " is " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot use int array to store floating-point numbers. So `printMatrix` method signature should be changed to `double[][]`.

And here is a method to calculate column sums

```
public static void calColSum(double[][] matrix){

    // number of columns
    int col = matrix[0].length;

    // array to hold column sum
    double[] colSums = new double[col];

    for (double[] row : matrix) {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            colSums[y] += row[y];
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x< colSums.length; x++){
        System.out.println("The sum of column " + x +" is: " + colSums[x]);
    }
}
```